# Tcl setAttribute method..How can i update only particular row in xml file

Tags: tcl, tdom

```
$intf setAttribute status "Shipped to Customer"
set status [$intf getAttribute status]
puts $status
```

in general status attribute is not there in that node...so I am setting it..to know whether
it is update or not i checked with getAttribute..so output was coming..
but this Attribute not seen in .xml file..
where i exactly missed....??
(or)
is there any best way to update only a specific row in .xml file only using tdom methods
I succedeed with temp file creation thats traditional process..
but i want to update row using tdom parser methos only..

Comment: Is the problem that the changes you make to the “document” aren't being reflected back into the file?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, I believe, that tDOM does not automatically reflect the changes you make to the document object model back into the file. Instead, its model is based on a *disconnected copy* of the contents of the file; to persist the changes, you have to re-serialize and save it out.

You'd do that with this:

```
# Save to a temporary file, just in case things go wrong...
set f [open $filename.tmp "w"]
$doc asXML -channel $f;   # Or the asHTML method if it's HTML to be saved
close $f

# Now do the atomic replace
file rename -force $filename.tmp $filename
```

It's as simple as that. (You need to know if it is XML or HTML; the serialization rules are subtly different in the two cases.)